# What is the noise whitening process?

Tags: discrete-signals, noise, digital-communications

I came across this process when working on OFDM in wireless communication. It's mentioned if we have two copies of a signal resulted from SIMO system (Single Rx Multiple Tx), we can process the noise whitening, after the FFT, in order to improve the quality of the signal.

What does mean the noise whitening, and what's its process?

Here is an example,  in the [paper](http://sndgw.snd.elec.keio.ac.jp/~sanada/TRANSACTION/2008IEICE_TransEB09.pdf).

After taking the DFT in OFDM, we supposed to get frequency response, so how w[k] is obtained?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation

Comment: "it's mentioned": Who mentions that, in what context? Cite, and give context.

Comment: @MarcusMüller .. 1- Why do you usually vote -1 for all my posts,? that really hurts. .. 2- I've read for example here: http://sndgw.snd.elec.keio.ac.jp/~sanada/TRANSACTION/2008IEICE_TransEB09.pdf    in sections 2.1 and similarly in other papers also. but this one which I'm interested in understanding it.

Comment: I don't usually vote -1 on your posts. This one was at least apparently underresearched and didn't give context. That's a severe question quality problem, so I downvoted; I'm sorry if it hurts you, but you might just want to post well-defined questions presenting your own research to avoid that hurt. Please go ahead and *edit* your question to include that reference.

Comment: Having read the section and especially the paragraphs after "As already stated, v(t) in Eq. (2) is the filtered noise.", I wonder what your *specific* question or unclarity is?

Comment: The question is, I couldn't understand what does mean if v(t) is filtered so how can it be whitened, what does mean whitening? .. and then according to the description, after making the FFT, we supposed to get frequency response, so how equation 12 and 11 are found? for example also Eq (6) from where w[k] is gotten? because as I said we supposed to frequency response after the DFT. .. hope my question is clear now

Comment: Re: what is whitening? See the first link I posted. (The fact that you need to diagonalize the correlation matrix is pretty straightforward if you know the definition of "White" w.r.t. auocorrelation, but I just googled for "whitening signal" and found the article. It was easy to find.)

Comment: Also, your comment explains your second question much more in detail than your edit. Please add the the equations to your question. *It's desirable to make questions as precise as possible.*

Comment: Is it whitening the signal or whitening the noise ? as I've read, it's whitening the noise. however, after the DFT is taken in OFDM, we supposed to get only X(F), so where is the noise which should be whitened ?

Comment: noise is a kind of signal. Just not the kind you want to have.

Comment: and how can I whiten it ? is it by whitening filter ?

Comment: by reading the link I posted first. Like, 2 hours ago...

Comment: OK, I'll try to understand it well, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a WSS (wide sense stationary) discrete-time random process (RP) with *i.i.d.* samples $X[n,s]$ whose auto-correlation sequence (ACF function) is $\phi_{XX}[m]$. We call a random process as **white-noise** if its ACF is the following:

$$ \phi_{XX}[m] = \begin{cases} 
{\sigma_X^2 ~~~~~, \text{ for } m=0 \\ 0 ~~~~~~~~, \text{ otherwise} }\end{cases} $$

This also means that the RP is **uncorrelated**. If a RP does not have this property then it's a **colored** noise. And it means its samples are **correlated**.

When a RP is colored, it may be possible to find an LTI filter which will try to remove the correlation between the samples of the noise and hence make it whitened. Such a filter is called either as a **decorrelator** or equivalently as **whitening** filter.

It's best described in the context of AR-p (Auto-Regressive) random processes generation through all pole filtering, where the whitening filter will be the **inverse** of that all-pole AR filter which generates the colored noise from an input white noise.

Comment: Hello .. OK, so let me explain the question, when taking the DFT in OFDM demodulator, we got two copies of signal, and it's described that noise whitening is done.  how can we perform that noise whitening? is it by that whitening filter or decorrelator ?

Comment: Since almost all communication engineering optimizations are based on the assumption of **additive white noise** on the received signals, when the noise is not white, their performance degrades from the theoretical maximum. A suggestion to improve the situation is to perform some processing on the received signal to make it whiter. And that's what the noise whitening block tries to achieve... In your case, the algorithm uses fractional oversampling for OFDM receiver which colors the received noise and therefore it's tried to be whitened to improve the reception performance.

Comment: Thank you so much .. So, what's the process of noise whitening? do you have any link which explains that OR matlab code example?

Comment: @Eng.Badr the simplest example is the inverse system of an AR process generator... Literature s abundant on this topic.

Comment: so, whitening the noise should improve the performance of signal, is that right? and the other thing, noise whitening can include any algorithm, there is not a specific algorithm or process which is called noise whitening .. is it right?

Comment: noise whitening can only make an improvement if the algortihm assumes that input noise is white. Otherwise it may even degrade the performance. Whitening is described as an **effect** in terms of ACFs rather than a system that does it. There is no unique system that will whiten every input. One should design a decorrelator according to input types (its statistics)

Comment: what's about the reference I provided above in the post. What does they mean by whitening? should that improve the performance because it's fractional sampling for same signal ?

Comment: yes it improves, because as they stated in the paper: "because of oversampling, the noise is colored, hence to make it white, we employ a whitening filter "... I don't know how they designed that filter however. May be you can contact the **author** and ask them ? why not ?